# Error on add library project in eclipse

Tags: android, jar, android-library

[image]

I added library project inside eclipse. But i got following error

```
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share] Versions found are:
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share] Path: D:\android 4 tools\work1\Share\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share]   Length: 349252
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share]   SHA-1: 612846c9857077a039b533718f72db3bc041d389
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share] Path: D:\android 4 tools\work1\Android-Feather\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share]   Length: 337562
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share]   SHA-1: 27c24d26e4c5d57976e6926367985548678e913c
[2012-10-09 11:25:38 - Share] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use same **android-support-v4.jar** library in both library and your main project.

To do this remove `android-support-v4.jar` file form both library and your main projects build path and then remove `android-support-v4.jar` from your libs path. Then reinsert same `android-support-v4.jar` in both library and main project. Then use `add to build path` to add lib to your projects.

This will solve your problem.

[image: How to add or remove support lib in project]

**How to Add Support Lib in Project :**

To add latest support lib to your android project do these steps :

1. Right click on your android project.
2. Select `Android Tools`
3. Then select `Add Support Library`

Then follow the screen instructions and this will add latest support library to your `libs` folder.

[image: How to add support lib to project]

Now right click on  `android-support-v4.jar` file in libs folder and Add it to build path as I described. You will have the latest support lib in your project.

**UPDATE**
As 'Doctoror Drive' said you only need to add `support library` in your `library project`. So only add `support library` to your `library project`.

Comment: I mean i want to delete lib file in Android-Feather and my main project. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes first delete android-support-v4.jar file from both folder then again add new android-support-v4.jar to library project and your main project. I updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Wrong. You only need one android-support-v4.jar file in the ActionBarSherlock project.