# Android Commonsware compile EmPubLite

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I am trying to compile EmPubLite tutorials but getting an error concerning the hierarchy of WebViewFragment.  Searches only come up with http://commonsware.com/Android/errata but not sure how to resolve this explanation.  Many files in this package use WebViewFragment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Terry

Comment: Please be more specific. I.e., post a logcat, relevant code, problem description, etc.

Comment: Agreed. The current version of those tutorials uses the native API Level 11+ `WebViewFragment`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, changed target back to Google API's after incorrectly changing it. Had to delete InstallReceiver.java, had error "The method build() is undefined for the type NotificationCompat.Builder" line 31, on mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());

Not going to worry about that for now. Any info on it would be great.

I was too focused on one error.  Once Mike M. asked for more info on logcat I noticed there was an error with mixed library versions android-support-v4.jar, deleted the one in libs folder and the project compiled fine.

Comment: Searched for "commonsware error NotificationCompat.Builder" and the first result was for this thread <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361324/issue-with-notificationcompact-builder-and-actionbarsherlock> in regards to error on mgr.notify. Fixed promptly.