# How to add two librarys with same name to Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, chromecast

I'm trying to add Google Play Services  and Google Play Services for froyo library to my proyect but Eclipse don't let me, the reason is I need the new library for Chromecast compatibility and need the old one to make work Admob on Android 2.2 devices.

Answer (score 0):

Use same android-support-v4.jar library in both library and your main project.

To do this remove android-support-v4.jar file form both library and your main projects build path and then remove android-support-v4.jar from your libs path. Then reinsert same android-support-v4.jar in both library and main project. Then use add to build path to add lib to your projects.

This will solve your problem.

Please read more [Error on add library project in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793722/error-on-add-library-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: Google Play Services is not a JAR file and has nothing to do with the support library, this is a project library and Eclipse don't let import two projects with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the business proposition. Froyo devices account for exactly 1.0% of the market (as of 1-MAY-2014). How many $$ worth of effort do you to spend to cater to that 1%?

Suggest you drop support for advertising for Froyo devices. Let them run the game for free.

Comment: It's about 3% of users for my app, that's about 5000 active users, source Google Analitycs.

I've already dropped support for Android 2.2 on the next update but's not the ideal solution for those 5K users.

Comment: You're not stopping them from using your app. You're just no longer displaying ads for them.