# Error when adding project library in eclipse

Tags: android

when adding `google-play-services_lib` in eclipse they fail and show the message: select

at least one project, this is the message:

[image]

whats the problem ?

thanx

Comment: check in the project box

Comment: seems there is already refearnce inside ur workspace, check the location of ur workspace and see if there is already lib present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use the same copy of `android-support-v4.jar` on the main and library project.

You can find a detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793722/error-on-add-library-project-in-eclipse) as well

Comment: the solution is not this,
the solution : delete the library project from workspace and re-import it.
but thanx anyway.